# Get data on basis of fields in Yii2

Tags: api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to get data on basis of fields in query param ie

```
users/1?fields=id,name
```

its give id and name using findOne

```
 User::findOne(1);
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": 'Jhon'
}
```

When

```
 users?fields=id,name
```

Its give all fields of user Model using findAll()

```
 User::findAll([$ids])
```

Result:

```
[
 {
  'id': 1
   'name': abc
   'age':30
   'dob':1970
   'email':abc@test.com
 },
 {
  'id': 2
   'name': abc
   'age':30
   'dob':1970
   'email':abc1@test.com
 },
```

Why findAll() not work like findOne() result

Comment: add `findOne` and `findAll` queries also.

Comment: can you show where are you using `findOne()` to select the columns? I dont think so that is correct

Comment: @InsaneSkull i update the question

Comment: Both query should return all fields. There is any `extraFields` configuration?

Comment: findOne return query param base fields @InsaneSkull

Comment: How you do that? `FindOne()` returns all fields until you select column externally.

Comment: You can use User::findAll(['id'=>$ids]); make sure $ids is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read [Data provider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers) and solve the problem